# Offlimit Address/Pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I will start with what I know: The C standard requires that NULL refers (somehow) to an invalid pointer which theoretically does not point to anything. So for example `malloc()` should never return a NULL pointer expect if an error occurs. I know that NULL is often represented as `((void*)0)` and the compiler translates this pointer-zero into an implementation defined address that meets the theoretical requirements of the symbolic NULL pointer (meaning essentially the address is unreachable).

Now let's say hypothetically I need another NULL (lets call it NULL2) which has the same exact characteristics as NULL but it can also be differentiated from NULL (NULL != NULL2). From what I understand of memory (which is not much) the NULL pointer often points to an address in a segment of memory which is off-limits. So what I mean is, usually there is an entire segment of memory which is off-limits not just a single address. So lets say I defined NULL2 as NULL+1 (I know that probably makes you cringe or maybe gag a little) would NULL2 theoretically (as I just defined it) also be unreachable (in the same sense that NULL is unreachable)?

I expect that answer would be entirely platform specific so examples are pretty much what I am looking for. But more generally is there any other pointer address that is defined by the ISO-C Standard to be invalid (or unreachable or whatever) in the same way as NULL. A general explanation of all address that are invalid (or offlimits) and why they are invalid would also be helpful. And if you feel the need to ask me "Why for the love of God I would need to do this" my answer would be I do not really need to do anything; its just a hypothetical question.

Comment: Put your text in paragraphs.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Well, hypothetically, if you want this you should create you own language with this specific behaviour. In C you can't, and you simply shouldn't be able to define two different kind of invalid pointers if they aren't going to represent different things

Answer (score 0):

No, NULL stands for zero.
Yes, using NULL + 1 behavior should be platform specific. However, I doubt address 0x0001 will be often available for programmer, so it could be considered a good not available address.

In your place I would do something such as this:

```
#define NULL2 null2()
void *null2()
{
    static char pointing_me_is_invalid;
    return &pointing_me_is_invalid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid just doing `NULL + 1` invokes undefined behaviour in C.

N1570 says in 6.5.6 Additive operators: (emphasis mine)

> 2 For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or
>   one operand shall be a **pointer to a complete object type** and the
>   other shall have integer type. (Incrementing is equivalent to adding
>   1.)

I don't think `NULL` is guaranteed to point to a complete object type. For example, `((void *)0)` doesn't.

I still can't understand why you need a another unreachable address constant even if it's "just a hypothetical question". If there really exists such an constant, it can't be portable. So simply use `0` or `NULL`, and your compiler will take care of the rest.